# Sorting a ListView using an ObjectDataSource with a LinkButton and ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, viewstate, objectdatasource

I am using a ListView to display paginated data:

```xml
<asp:ListView ID="listOfItems" runat="server" DataSourceID="ItemsDataSource" EnableModelValidation="True" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemRowContainer">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="tablecontainer">
            <div class="pagination-top">
                <custom:TablePaginationControl ID="TablePaginationControl1" runat="server" ControlID="listOfItems" ShowPageSizeList="true" />
            </div>
            <table class="list-view">
                <tr>
                    <th class="first-column" width="350px">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="SortByName" runat="server" CommandArgument="Name" CommandName="SortMainList" OnCommand="SortItems" Text="<%$ Resources:Name %>"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </th>
                    ...
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <tr runat="server" id="ItemRowContainer" />
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    ...
</asp:ListView>
```

The datasource definition:

```xml
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ItemsDataSource" runat="server" EnablePaging="True" InsertMethod="AddItems" SelectCountMethod="SelectItemsCount" SelectMethod="SelectItems" TypeName="SHLCentral.TheLibrary.Web.View.DocumentManagementControl, ClientPortal.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd2852a10d692fb9" UpdateMethod="UpdateItems">
    ...
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The revelant code behind is made of these two methods:

```
public IEnumerable<ListDocumentsResult> SelectItems(
    int maximumRows,
    int startRowIndex)
{
    var results = Controller.ListDocuments(new ListDocumentsRequest());

    PropertyInfo sortProperty;
    try
    {
        sortProperty = typeof (ListDocumentsResult).GetProperty((string) ViewState["mainListSortColumn"]);
    }
    catch
    {
        sortProperty = null;
    }
    Func<ListDocumentsResult, object> sortFunction = sortProperty == null
                            ? (Func<ListDocumentsResult, object>) (ldr => ldr.LastUpdatedDate)
                            : (ldr => sortProperty.GetValue(ldr, new object[0]));

    return
        (sortProperty == null || !((bool) ViewState["mainListSortAsc"])
             ? results.OrderByDescending(sortFunction)
             : results.OrderBy(sortFunction))
            .Skip(startRowIndex)
            .Take(maximumRows);
}

protected void SortItems(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "SortMainList")
    {
        var sortColumn = (string) e.CommandArgument;
        if ((string)ViewState["mainListSortColumn"] == sortColumn)
        {
            ViewState["mainListSortAsc"] = !(bool)ViewState["mainListSortAsc"];
        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["mainListSortAsc"] = true;
            ViewState["mainListSortColumn"] = sortColumn;
        }
        DataBind();
    }
}
```

So my intention this: when the users clicks on the `LinkButton` contained in the "Name" column header (I left out all but one column for clarity), the `SortItems` method is called: it sets the sorted column name and sort order into the `ViewState`, then reloads the `ListView` using the `DataBind` method. In the Select method of the `ObjectDataSource`, we read this `ViewState` values and use them to order the data.

Putting breakpoints on all these methods, I can see there is this sequence of calls when I click the `LinkButton`:

- `OnLoad`
- `SortItems`
- `SelectItems`

The problem I have is that when I get to the `SelectItems` method, the `ViewState` is totally empty (it has 0 keys): if I set a breakpoint on the Load method of the page, I see the control containing all this is only loaded once. The `DataBind` method does not seem to trigger any loading of the control, it seems to be just triggering the `SelectItems` method of a new instance of the control (meaning that if, instead of using `ViewState`, I set an instance field in the `SortItems` method, the field is null when getting in the `SelectItems` method).

I am sure that the `ViewState` is active on the page (I can find the `ViewState` keys on the browser side using a Firefox extension for instance).

There is something not quite clear to me about the life cycle of the page/control. Could someone explain what it is to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exist much, much simpler approach.

First, instead of a custom `CommandName`, you put a built-in name into the sort link button. The name is `Sort`.

You have then

```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="SortByName" runat="server" CommandArgument="Name" CommandName="Sort" />
```

Then, on your `ObjectDataSource` you add the `SortParameterName` to be something like `OrderBy`:

```
   <ObjectDataSource .... SortParameterName="OrderBy" />
```

Then you modify your data provider method to be:

```
 public IEnumerable<ListDocumentsResult> SelectItems(
   string OrderBy,
   int maximumRows,
   int startRowIndex)
```

The data source will provide the value automatically based on the command argument (`Name`) and it will automatically append `DESC` whenever you click the command button for the second time (it is because the `ListView` persists the state of sort order in its viewstate automatically, you don't have to reinvent this!)

Then, you don't need this ugly delegates to order by strings for linq. Instead, download the Dynamic Linq library:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

find the `Dynamic.cs` file, include it in your project and it will add a bunch of additional linq operators, including the `OrderBy` which accepts strings and which automatically supports `DESC` (!).

You then just

```
 public IEnumerable<ListDocumentsResult> SelectItems(
   string OrderBy,
   int maximumRows,
   int startRowIndex)
 {

     Controller.ListDocuments(new ListDocumentsRequest())
        .OrderBy(OrderBy)
        .Skip(startRowIndex)
        .Take(maximumRows);
 }
```

This is just as simple!

Be warned though that there's a small bug (or an inconvenience) in the dynamic linq - it throws an exception when the sort order is empty.

Find then this code (line 47 and down)

```
    public static IQueryable OrderBy(this IQueryable source, string ordering, params object[] values) {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (ordering == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("ordering");
```

and change it manually to

```
    public static IQueryable OrderBy(this IQueryable source, string ordering, params object[] values) {
        if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( ordering ) ) return source;
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (ordering == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("ordering");
```

Done.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. For a reason I cannot recall, I thought the SortParameterName property was only used when an ObjectDataSource was used with a GridView (as opposed to ListView). But no, it actually works as you said. I haven't looked into Dynamic.cs yet, so I still had of course to adapt my code to handle the "Name DESC" case, - which isn't making my code any prettier... But it works.

Comment: You don't have to adapt to anything. As I said, the "Name" and "Name DESC" will be passed automatically by the listview and the dynamic linq will also handle this automatically.

Comment: Yes I know, I just meant to say I haven't looked into dynamic linq yet so I just checked that the solution to my sort issue was working ok so I could set the response as answer. I'm sure the dynamic linq will eventually make it prettier.

Comment: Is there any way to adapt this to sort by multiple columns? When I tried it, on the descending sort it only ordered the second column descending and kept the ascending sort on the first column (I'm doing a sort on Surname, First Name)

Comment: Never thought about it and the quick answer would be : not necessarily. Can't think of an easy way to have this working for multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

If the `SelectMethod` is not static, the `ObjectDataSource` control will create a new instance of the type specified in `TypeName` and call the method on that instance.

You either need to add a parameter for the sort expression to your select method and set the [`SortParameterName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.sortparametername.aspx) on the `ObjectDataSource`, or you need to handle the [`ObjectCreating` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.objectcreating.aspx) and set the `ObjectInstance` to the existing control instance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation to the actual misunderstanding I had with the life cycle of the control instance. I decided to go for the SortParameterName, handling the ObjectCreating event seems overkill and not really easy to explain to the next developer who will read my code.